# Protégé-OWL: "Multi slot" Object

Tags: object, properties, owl, protege, manchester-syntax

I'm trying to model a 4x4 grid for a project in protege ( Manchester owl format), i have a Row class to represent the rows of the grid and i would to like to specify somehow that the Row class must have 4 cells ( i also have the cell class).
Is it in any way possible to make that? Through a Object property or an axiom?

edit: I already specify that a Row must have Cells

```
Row hasCells some Cells
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the 'Class description' view:

[image: Class description view]